# Cookies in .NET core 2.0 with SAML authentication

Tags: .net, cookies, asp.net-core, saml-2.0, okta-api

I am new to SAML and .NET core 2.0 cookie authentication. I am trying to implement SAML 2.0 compliance in a .NET core 2.0 using Okta as an IdP. I have read through a lot of .NET core documentation around [authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but there is no authentication scheme for a federated IdP using the SAML 2.0 flow wherein the IdP calls back the SP with a SAML once it is done authenticating the user.

The flow is as follows

```
Client (calls SP for accessing data) => SP

SP (redirects client to IdP) -> Client => IdP

IdP(authenticates user and calls the callback URL for SP) => SP

SP (serves content to client with cookie for future requests) => Client

Client (requests another resource + appends cookie) => SP

SP (validates cookie [ login again if invalid | continue if valid ] and serves content) => Client
```

I also tried reading through ASP .NET Core code samples for [Cookies](https://github.com/aspnet/Docs/tree/master/aspnetcore/security/authentication/cookie/samples/2.x/CookieSample) but it implements a method `HttpContext.Authentication.SignInAsync` that has been marked as obsolete by Microsoft.

While working on this I tried to use the `using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens.Saml2` nuget package for parsing Saml2 but without an authentication scheme I could not get far in my custom implementation.

Any code samples or libraries that I can use to implement this flow will be helpful.

Comment: What SAML stack are you using? - https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/i-need-a-saml-stack-now-63d9691e2d43

Comment: I was looking for one if available. The beginning of the article describes me write now :D Will try out one of them. Do you have any recommendations for .NET core 2.0?

Comment: As per the article, ComponentSpace, Rock Solid Knowledge, Sustainsys,